# Development of なんか？

Tags: history, syntax

Is there anymore to the usage of なんか that isn't saying "something", but rather something like, or along the lines of? I know the two are very similar, but using なんか at the end of a sentence seems to be very clear syntactically, while using it to modify a noun seems weird, especially given the か at the end- further kanji isn't generally used, I don't think. So is there more to it? Is there a more formal way of saying it that would make sense syntactically?

Comment: Compare など and なんて.

Comment: The comparison just makes me more confused, where do those come from?

Comment: Could you give an example or two so we can make sure which なんか you're talking about?

Comment: I forget what exactly my friend said- it was なんか followed by a noun. She was trying to say "Something like a-".
There is more than one なんか?

Comment: Are you sure it was なんか followed by a noun and not preceded by a noun?

Comment: I think that's how she used it, she could have been wrong.

Answer (score 5):

My answer will be based on the assumption that OP is talking about when 「なんか」 is indeed followed, not preceded, by a noun as s/he so states in the comments (but not in the question).

In **informal** conversation, there actually exists such a structure.

> "なんか + Noun + みたいな（のような） + Noun"

For instance, I have little appetite when I have a fever.  Since I do not want to eat a regular meal, I would say to someone:

> 「なんかゼリーかヨーグルトみたいなもの、いくつか[買]{か}ってきてくれる？」
>
> "Could you go get some jello or yogurt type of things for me?"

In this sentence, your TL "along the lines of" is spot-on.　**Note that in this case, 「なんか」 can be replaced by 「なにか」.**

**EDIT:**

Just in case, I will briefly talk about when 「なんか」 is preceded by a noun.  There are two main usages of this structure.

1) Citing an instance.

> A: どこか[暖]{あたた}かいところに行きたいなあ。"I'd love to go someplace warm."
>
> B: 暖かいところ？サイパンなんかどう？ "Someplace warm?  How about Saipan?"

2) Making light of something.

> 「[愛]{あい}なんかいらない！[金]{かね}が[欲]{ほ}しい！」 "I don't want love!  I want money!"

**Note that when 「なんか」 is preceded by a noun, it cannot be replaced by 「なにか」.**

Comment: l'électeurさん, Is なんか in 2) used only with negative constructions? If affirmative is possible, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

It can be used in front of adjectives to convey the sense of "somewhat" (e.g. なんか強い = "somewhat strong").  Is that close to what you're getting at?

Comment: I know the use- I just don't know where it come from. I suppose the syntax label might have been misleading...